# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, closures

I am trying to connect three file `rule.js`, `event.js`, `action.js` using import and export in javaScript.

The functions in `event.js` will get the data from the browser and when the and condition gets fulfilled then it will run the function from the `rule.js` and after that action will be get executed.

// rule.js

```js
import{actionOne} from 'action.js';
var scrollAndTime = (function(){
    return function(){
        console.log(actionOne());
    }
})();

export{scrollAndTime};
```

// event.js

```js
import { scrollAndTime } from 'rule';

var scrollPercentage = (function(){
    var scrollRun = false;  // This is for future use
    if(!scrollRun){
        return function(scroll){
            console.log("I am Scroll.");
            var height = document.documentElement,
                body   = document.body,
                st     = 'scrollTop',
                sh     = 'scrollHeight';
                scrollRun = scroll;
            var scrollPercent = (height[st]||body[st]) / ((height[sh]||body[sh]) - height.clientHeight) * 100;
            return scrollPercent;
        }
    }
})();

var timeSpent = (function(){
    var time    = new Date();
    var timeRun = false,  // This is for future use
        startTime = time.getTime();
    if(!timeRun){
        return function(){ // call this function by timeSpent()(); 
            console.log("I am Time.");
            return (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
        }
    }
})();


// Handling and condition between scrollPercentage and timeSpent
var and=false;

addEventListener("click",function(){
    if(!and){
        var scrollAndTimeSpent=false;
        if(scrollPercentage()>70 && timeSpent()>15000){
            // this.alert("Executed!");
            and=true;
            scrollAndTimeSpent=true;
        }
        if(scrollAndTimeSpent){
            // Tell rule engine that I have completed
            // Execute this function.
            scrollAndTime();
        }
    }
})
```

// action.js

```js
var actionOne = (function(){
    return function(){
        // Do the following things and return the required thing.
        return "ActionOne done!";
    }
})();

export{actionOne};
```

// index.html - This is the page which is using these js files.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Rule Engine</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="event.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in this when I am using type="module" I get 
(Access to Script at'file:///Users/praveenkumarrana/Desktop/Projects/ruleengine/event.mjs' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.) 
error.

And when I don't use it I get (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {  in Chrome.)` error.

Comment: (To summarize the duplicate question - you can't load JS modules from the filesystem. You need a web server.)

Comment: Yes this was error caused because I was not using server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this line,

> file:///Users/praveenkumarrana/Desktop/Projects/ruleengine/event.mjs

I assume you are running this code from the file system (without passing through a local server).
Due to the fact that ES6 modules are liable to **same-origin policy**, you can't import them from the file system or cross-origin without a CORS header. Essentially, you have to **run this code from a server** or **disable same-origin in the browser(for testing)**.